# Seems like wrong shell script: cat

Tags: linux, shell, cat

I have a problem using this `start.sh` script.
When I type 
`./start.sh`, it doesn't work.
I mean, it makes no errors but it does nothing.

When I open this file using VIM (I really want to upload the image, but I can't because I registered this site just few days ago)
the lines from `import sys,math,random`
to `print '\n'` are 
all colored red.
After `EOS`,
the color is normally shown.
If I type `#` in front of `cat`, I mean, `#cat <<EOS | python > target.txt`, the colors are changed.

So I think this line:

```
cat <<EOS | python > target.txt
```

is wrong. How can I correct it?

```
#!/bin/sh

if [ "$1" = clean ]; then
rm -f *.log *.dat target.txt
exit
fi

num=1
length=1000
period=50

cat <<EOS | python > target.txt
import sys,math,random
funcs = [
lambda t : (0.8 * math.sin(t), 0.8 * math.cos(t)),
lambda t : (0.3 * math.sin(t), 0.3 * math.cos(t)),
lambda t : (0.8 * math.sin(3 * t), 0.8 * math.cos(t)),
lambda t : (0.8 * math.cos(t), 0.8 * math.sin(3 * t)),

lambda t : (0.4 * math.sin(2 * t) + 0.4, 0.8 * math.cos(t)),
lambda t : (0.4 * math.sin(2 * t) - 0.4, 0.8 * math.cos(t)),
lambda t : (0.8 * math.sin(2 * t), 0.4 * math.cos(t) + 0.4),
lambda t : (0.8 * math.sin(2 * t), 0.4 * math.cos(t) - 0.4),

lambda t : (0.4 * math.cos(t) + 0.4, 0.8 * math.sin(2 * t)),
lambda t : (0.4 * math.cos(t) - 0.4, 0.8 * math.sin(2 * t)),
lambda t : (0.8 * math.cos(t), 0.4 * math.sin(2 * t) + 0.4),
lambda t : (0.8 * math.cos(t), 0.4 * math.sin(2 * t) - 0.4),

lambda t : (0.4 * math.sin(t) + 0.4, 0.8 * math.cos(t)),
lambda t : (0.4 * math.sin(t) - 0.4, 0.8 * math.cos(t)),
lambda t : (0.8 * math.sin(t), 0.4 * math.cos(t) - 0.4),
lambda t : (0.8 * math.sin(t), 0.4 * math.cos(t) + 0.4),

lambda t : (0.8 * math.sin(t), 0.8 * math.cos(2 * t)),
lambda t : (0.8 * math.sin(t), -0.8 * math.cos(2 * t)),
lambda t : (0.8 * math.cos(2 * t), 0.8 * math.sin(t)),
lambda t : (-0.8 * math.cos(2 * t), 0.8 * math.sin(t)),

lambda t : (0.3 * math.sin(t) + 0.5, 0.3 * math.cos(t) + 0.5),
lambda t : (0.3 * math.sin(t) + 0.5, 0.3 * math.cos(t) - 0.5),
lambda t : (0.3 * math.sin(t) - 0.5, 0.3 * math.cos(t) + 0.5),
lambda t : (0.3 * math.sin(t) - 0.5, 0.3 * math.cos(t) - 0.5)
]
def gen_sigma():
sigma = [0.01, 0.05]
n = 0
while True:
    yield sigma[n % len(sigma)]
    n += 1
gen = gen_sigma()

for f in funcs:
sigma = gen.next()
for n in xrange($num):
    m = random.randint(0, 1000)
    for t in [x * ((2 * math.pi) / $period) for x in xrange(m, $length+m)]:
        print '\t'.join([str(x + random.gauss(0, sigma)) for x in f(t)])
    print '\n'
EOS

if [ x`which rnn-learn` == x ]; then
path1=../../src/rnn-learn/
else
path1=
fi
${path1}rnn-learn -c config.txt target.txt
```

Comment: From where did you get this Python script wrapped in Bourne Shell? I suggest you check with the author.

Comment: If I can do, I did it. But I can't contact with him. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing self-evidently wrong with the script.  The section that is marked in red is a 'here document' which runs from the line after the line containing `<<EOS` to the line containing just `EOS`.  The here document is provided as standard input to Python, which writes its output to the file `target.txt`.  The remainder of the script runs the `rnn-learn` command on the `target.txt` file, guided (I guess) by the configuration file `config.txt`.

When you put a `#` in front of the line containing the `cat` command, that becomes a comment, so the following lines are 'just shell script' — they aren't meaningful as shell script, but `vim` would be hard pressed to know that (it's an editor!).  So, it changes the colour of the lines because they aren't part of a here document any more.

The `cat` really isn't necessary.  The line could have been written as:

```
python > target.txt <<EOS
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I need to check another point